# Unable to import and use SSZipArchive in Xcode 10.2 Swift 4 by manually drag and drop. Lot's of semantic issue errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ssziparchive

I created Fresh new Xcode iOS project and followed below steps.

1. Drag & Drop SSZipArchive folder in Xcode project.
2. Created Briging Header and imported Header file I.e. #Import "SSZipArchive.h"
3. Added libz.tbd and security framework to a target

Then after it gave lot's of semantic issues. Can somebody please help me on this. It Would be really helpful if there is a video of importing this files in XCode iOS project. Please help me.

For reference please see screenshot below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehukJ.jpg)

Can somebody please help me on importing manually.

[image]

Comment: @Cœur can you please help me to import manually in Xcode 10.2 swift 4.

Comment: follow the steps under manual. https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Comment: @BenRockey Yes i followed those steps last step(4) i was not able to do it how can i do it ion xcode 10.2 and swift 4.

Comment: search GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS in buildsettings and add : HAVE_INTTYPES_H HAVE_PKCRYPT HAVE_STDINT_H HAVE_WZAES HAVE_ZLIB MZ_ZIP_NO_SIGNING $(inherited)                  in debug section

Comment: @Eshwar for information, when you write `@Cœur` in a comment, I'll only be notified if I've previously added a comment on the post, or edited the post. I just saw your comment by luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive from this

1. Add the SSZipArchive folder that contain minizip folder to your project.
2. Add the libz and libiconv libraries to your target.
3. Add the Security framework to your target.
   [image]
4. Add the following GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS: HAVE_INTTYPES_H HAVE_PKCRYPT HAVE_STDINT_H HAVE_WZAES HAVE_ZLIB MZ_ZIP_NO_SIGNING $(inherited).
   [image]
5. Remove info.plist under target-> build phase-> copy bundle resources.

Comment: Thank you, I'll link to your tutorial next time. ;)

Comment: Note that from your screenshot, you have `$(inherited)` twice, and with a typo the second time: you actually only need it once.

Comment: Hi @Cœur .Still i'm facing issues, Can you kindly create one video importing into xcode. This will be a great help to me.

Comment: @Ben Rockey I'm facing issues while creating build. Can you pls create one video importing into XCode manually. Thanks.

Comment: @Eshwar please list the issues you facing while creating the build.

Comment: If i install it through XCODE run to simulator/device it's working fine unzipping files. I'm using Admin jenkins Xmake software to create ios build Where as after creating ipa file that unzipping functionality is not working.

Comment: I think we copied only in DEBUG GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS so that's why in release(I mean ipa) not able to unzip. Am i correct?? Ben Rockey and Coeur.

Comment: This line i'm adding in release hope it works.     RELEASE=1 HAVE_INTTYPES_H HAVE_PKCRYPT HAVE_STDINT_H HAVE_WZAES HAVE_ZLIB $(inherited)